# How to Return Kotlin/Native String?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I Build a Kotlin/Native Project

My androidMain code is

```
class MyTest {
    @CName("Java_sample_MyTest_callMe")
    fun callMe(): Int {
        return 99
    }

    @CName("Java_sample_MyTest_callHello")
    fun callHello(): String {
        return "MyBook"
    }
}
```

Then My App Code is

```
class MyTest {
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("AndroidNative64")
        }
    }

    external fun callMe(): Int
    external fun callHello(): String
}
```

and Call it

```
// OK
val v2 = "" + MyTest().callMe()
Log.d("TAG", v2)

// Error
val v3 = MyTest().callHello()
Log.d("TAG", v3)
```

Error Message is

```
invalid reference returned from java.lang.String sample.MyTest.callHello()
```

How to fix it
Thanks You Very Much

Comment: Why are you calling `.toString()` when your v3 is already String type?

Comment: And also I think you're using `@CName` annotation wrong way, as far as it is created for the top-level functions, not for the class members. Example of `@CName`s usage can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/backend.native/tests/produce_dynamic/simple/)